# Heroku and Django: How to use file server for storing and editing user files

Tags: python, django, heroku

I built a Django app that has some .txt files in a folder on under the project root dir as shown below.

```
<pre>
[projectname]/
├── [projectname]/
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── urls.py
│   └── wsgi.py
└── manage.py
├── [<b> myfiles </b>]/
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
│   ├── file3.txt
│   └── file4.txt
└── [myApp]/
</pre>
```

I specify the files paths when I am running the django app on my local machine. Now, I tried running my app on Heroku, but the not app does not work when I tried reference any of my files to do some processing. Is there a way that I can use a file server (external or internal to Heroku) where I can store my files on and then update them in via the django app (by the users) and save them back to file server?

In my app, when a user creates a new project, in the background a function will create a folder for the user and then copy the files in [myfiles] folder to the user's new project folder.

Also, users can enter data through forms that I want to to save to .rdf files and then save to the file server.

In the end, I the file system would look like this:

```
<pre>
[file system root]/
├── [<b> myfiles </b>]/
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
│   ├── file3.txt
│   └── file4.txt
├── [<b> user1 </b>]/
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
│   ├── file3.txt
│   └── graphfile1
├── [<b> user2 </b>]/
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── graphfile1
│   ├── file3.txt
│   └── file4.txt
├── [<b> user3 </b>]/
│   ├── file1.txt
│   ├── file2.txt
│   ├── graphfile1
│   └── file4.txt
....
</pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a service like S3, use django-storages package.

And one thing, in Heroku the data is not persistent. Every time the dyno is restart, the files restart to the original image too. More info here: https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out. Also, I see where S3 is used mainly for downloading and uploading of files. In my current application I want to take in user input using form fields, then process the user's data, then create a file with .owl extension. Next, I will then upload the .owl file to the file server. At another time, the user can request the file which can be download for more processing, save again back to the file server.